# Java application as a service - what are the options out there?

Tags: java, web-services, api, cloud, saas

I have a Java application. I can expose it using web services or REST (JAX-WS or JAX-RS).

Now I actually want to run it "in a cloud" and expose it as a service. I have read around that there are services e.g. Apigee, Rackspace, Google App Engine... The idea is that I don't want to worry about scale and performance. I want that handled by the host.

What are the options for Java?

Thanks,
David.

Comment: I've voted to close. This sounds like a request for a favourite/preferred off-site resource, which is generally frowned upon because it ages rather quickly. It's also rather opinion-based, but I can't vote to close for two reasons.

Comment: This is absolutely off-topic for Stack Overflow; SO is not a recommendation service, the question is asking for a list of tools and is primarily opinion-based.

Comment: I'm not asking for your favorite / opinion. I'm asking for a simple list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of homework, here's what I am gathering:

This is really about Java PaaS offerings (platform as a service).

In addition to what I previously mentioned,

- Google App Engine
- Rackspace
- Apigee

it's worth adding:

- Jelastic
- CloudBees

There's also a guide - albeit old - from InfoQ that can be read [here](http://www.infoq.com/articles/paas_comparison).

Comment: Also, a few comparisons (specifically for Java) that Jelastic published (so there is some bias - but the info can help you decide because a lot of it is indeed factual): http://blog.jelastic.com/2012/02/09/jelastic-versus-heroku/, http://blog.jelastic.com/2012/02/27/google-app-engine-vs-jelastic/, http://blog.jelastic.com/2013/04/16/elastic-beanstalk-vs-jelastic/

Answer (score 0):

Depends on amount of money you can spend.
[This cloud hosting](http://jelastic.com/) seems interesting.

Comment: Thanks! Assuming money is not an issue, what would you choose?

Answer (score 0):

There's Heroku too, or even AWS.

Comment: Re. AWs, it'd actually be AWS Beanstalk  http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/

Answer (score 0):

Amazon AWS provides auto-scaling features that you can configure so you don't have to "worry about scale" day to day, though you do have to set it up in the first place (you will also have to monitor your bill in case you are scaling big-time ;) ).  It works well and provides decent monitoring/visualization if you are happy to do the set up.

I can't say whatthe other systems you are investigating have to offer in terms of automatic scaling though.